# Tight upper-bound on dependent events

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Given $r$ r.v.s $x_k$: $x_k=1$ with probability $p_k$ and $0$ otherwise. Let $s_i=\sum_{j=1}^r c_{ij}p_j$ where $c_{ij}\in[0,1]$, $1\le i\le n$. Let $E_i$ denote the event $\sum_{j=1}^r c_{ij}x_j>(1+\delta)s_i$. I want to compute an upper-bound of $\Pr(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i)$. A loose bound is $\sum_{i=1}^n E_i$. Another bound is $1-\Pi_{i} [1-\Pr(E_i)]$. However, since $E_i$ are mutually dependent, how to derive a tighter bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, really nothing can be said here. Very much will depend on how close the rows of the matrix $(c_{ij})$ are to one another.

Even in the very special case when $p_k=1/2$ for all $k$, this is a very difficult problem, considered in detail in Chapter 5 "Bernoulli Processes" of Talagrand's book [*Upper and Lower Bounds for Stochastic Processes*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-54075-2).

Arguably the main idea there is that of generic chaining, going back to Kolmogorov. If you have enough information on how close the rows of the matrix $(c_{ij})$ are to one another, you can try a custom adaptation of the generic chaining method.

Comment: Thank you Losif for your comment and pointing out the reference. I now see that the problem is intuitively understandable but hard to solve. My original thought is: suppose two events $E_i$ and $E_j$ "overlap" on only a single $x_k$ where $c_{ik}$ and $c_{jk}$ are non-zero; I was expecting results like $\Pr(E_i\cup E_j)\le a\cdot[\Pr(E_i)+ \Pr(E_j)]$ with some $a<1$.

Comment: '"overlap" on only a single $x_k$": What do you mean by that? It is generally not a good idea to denote a random variable and its values by the same symbol -- this creates confusion.

Comment: My comment was not clear. What I meant is that if $(c_{ij})$ is sparse (having many zero elements), $E_i$ and $E_j$ can be correlated, and we may hope to have some result. But I now see that it is still highly intractable.

Comment: I have accepted your answer:)